# What VS Code extension can I use to go to declaration on ctrl + click?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> and it goes to the declaration in the PHP, like this:

[image]

The problem is, my files do not only have PHP. It doesn't work with JavaScript functions as you can see:

[image]

Is there any extension that make it work with JavaScript? I know there is an extension that works for CSS, and I'm using it.

Comment: I see that question is still open, meanwhile VSCode does that for me. I'm not sure if it's through an extension, though I have a few active. But even with all JS-related ones disabled, it still does, so I assume it must be built-in by now. If it is resolved for you too, can you close the question, pls? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ctrl+Click Go To Definition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CtrlClickGoToDefinition) extension

Comment: this extension was incorporated in vscode. It should work like that, but in this case only works to php functions, and not javascript